# I saw you once - Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I saw you once.
>
> I killed you twice.
>
> I asked you thrice.
>
> You deny all the time.
>
> You say nothing, I say all.
>
> You deny my existence, in the end.
>
> You view me as less, time to get you dressed.
>
> Pay me a dime, and I will check your time.
>
> None left, come with me.
>
> Life is here, so you and me.

## Who am I?

Comment: Could it have a link with the catholic religion? Jesus lived twice, and his apostles was asked three times and denied each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's a stretch, but perhaps the answer could be...

> An accomplice testifying against me

I saw you once.

> You only saw me once in court.

I killed you twice.

> You "killed" me once when you got me caught, and you "killed" me twice when you got me sentenced.

I asked you thrice.

> You asked me three times to confess.

You deny all the time.

> Of course I'm going to deny the crime.

You say nothing, I say all.

> I never admit to being guilty. You confess to everything.

You deny my existence in the end.

> By the end of the trial, I pretend to not even know you.

You view me as less, time to get you dressed.

> I see you as less than me, so you get me dressed in a prisoners uniform.

Pay me a dime, and I will check your time.

> Even though you got me locked up, if I pay you enough money, you'll do more crimes for me. Or perhaps I can pay you money to reduce my time in prison by saying you lied in court.

None left, come with me.

> If I want to keep living as criminal and no one wants to work with me, I have to return to my original accomplice.

Life is here, so you and me.

> In the end, my life as a criminal ends up simply being you, the accomplice and me, the mastermind. Or the accomplice ends up being put in jail too, and they're the only one I can end up trusting in there.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer?**

The answer could be:

> Nothing

I saw you once.

> Emptiness is singularity, so it saw me once (?)

I killed you twice.

> Nothing's going to kill you twice.

I asked you thrice.

> (?)

You deny all the time.

> You don't hear empty space.

You say nothing, I say all.

> Empty space (nothing) is everywhere.

You deny my existence, in the end.

> You don't want the universe (mostly empty space) to end.

You view me as less, time to get you dressed.

> You view nothing as less. (I have no idea in the second half)

Pay me a dime, and I will check your time.

> (?)

None left, come with me.

> Nothing.

Life is here, so you and me.

> It looks like there will be nothing after this.

Comment: I guess `You deny my existence, in the end` sounds like we refuse to admit the eptiness of death, with religions they are heaven or afterlifes

Comment: @Therandomguy maybe

Answer (score 0):

Well,it (partial answer) could be an

> Alarm piece( with snooze feature)

As
 I saw you once

> I can look at an alarm clock to get the time

I killed you twice

> A set alarm rings lively twice a day, requiring me to make it silence(kill) twice a day.

I asked you thrice.

> Perhaps with a snooze feature enabled, I can request an alarm clock to wake me up thrice

You deny all the time.

> It races with the time...by denying it ( a little stretch)

You say nothing, I say all.

> Obvious ?!

You deny my existence, in the end.

> To be provided

You view me as less, time to get you dressed.

> Winding an alarm clock, perhaps.

Pay me a dime, and I will check your time.

> Time telling service for very less money

None left, come with me.

> No analog alarm clocks, perhaps, nowadays.

Life is here, so you and me.

> To be provided

Comment: In the viewpoint you take in your answer, you yourself are the "I" from the question. But the question is posed the other way around. It is not you that saw the answer once and killed it twice, and so one, instead it is the answer that saw you once, killed you twice, etc.

Comment: Good interpretation... I tried interpreting the puzzle based on the description of clues....especially from line #  *4* onwards.